# Junit don't run in Eclipse 4.3: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/RemoteTestRunner

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

I have done a fresh install of Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler).
I installed the m2e (Maven Integration) plugin.
I created a new workspace.

Then I imported my maven project (https://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/).

But whatever I do when I run junit tests from Ecplise, I keep throwing at me :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/RemoteTestRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I tried to add junit in the library, tried to add the library Junit4 to the running configuration.

I tried to ask Google, but found nothing.

I tried to rebuild manually my project, nothing changed.

I tried to run Maven -> Update project, clean my project to force a rebuild.

There is no error in my project.

Can someone can give me any hint ? Where to look or try ?

Answer (score 0):

From your project, right click, choose Properties, Then select Java Build Path, Add Library, Select Junit 3 or 4,  and press Finish.

From your test, right click, and Run As Junit

Comment: That was one of my first try. It failed.

Comment: I think maven project can't resolve some dependencies in Eclipse. I transform this project to an usual Eclipse project, manually checked the dependencies, and it works.